# can't get the sessionFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate, sessionfactory, null-pointer

my java project with spring and hibernate,can't get the sessionFactory.it's null all the time when i use it. the configuration:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="test" class="test.Test">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>`
```

the main code of Test.java is

```
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    public SessionFactory getSessionFacoty(){
        return this.sessionFactory;
    }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Test test = new Test();
    System.out.println(test.sessionFactory);
}
```

Comment: where and how do you think sessionFactory is getting set/initialized ? Its not, it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test in the `main` method doesn't actually use Spring for injection.  You need to load the `applicationContext.xml` then get the `test` bean from that.

So you could do something like this in your main:

```
ApplicationContext context =
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"applicationContext.xml"});

Test test = (Test)context.getBean("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get Test object from spring context as well. Load your config xml and create the context and get the object from the context

eg.

```
Test test = (Test) context.getBean("test");
```